# PayPal is returning API error code 10486 instead of 10417. Why?

Tags: paypal

Starting today (5th of June 2013), I am getting back API error code 10486 in the DoExpressCheckoutPayment response instead of API error code 10417 I got in the past.

What is this new error code and how should I handle it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Starting the 5th of June 2013 PayPal will return API error code 10486 instead of 10417 in the DoExpressCheckoutPayment API response in the majority of cases.
Both 10417 mean 'transaction cannot complete', but with API error code 10486 you can re-redirect the user back to PayPal to select a differing funding source (rather than having to call SetExpressCheckout and re-initiate the entire transaction flow).

There is a [HowTo guide available](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec_fundingfailure10486/) with more information, but basically all you need to do is re-use the existing redirect URL you would've used earlier.
E.g. https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-ABCDE12345

The buyer will be re-redirected to PayPal and be able to select a new funding source.
The buyer will subsequently be redirected to the same RETURNURL you specified in your first SetExpressCheckout request.

[image: 10486 redirect flow]

**Note:** You can find a full list of all PayPal API error codes, along with their short and long messages [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/).

Answer (score 2):

My logs show three types of errors following the DoExpressCheckout() call.

The new **10486** (This transaction couldn't be completed., (This transaction couldn't be completed. Please redirect your customer to PayPal.)) looks like it is handled nicely by redirecting the user back into PayPal.

I also see the **10417** (Transaction cannot complete., (Instruct the customer to retry the transaction using an alternative payment method from the customers PayPal wallet. The transaction did not complete with the customers selected payment method.)). How should I handle this. Can I also redirect the user back to PayPal as in 10486 or display an error and the initial checkout page?

Finally, I see **10537** (Risk Control Country Filter Failure, (The transaction was refused because the country was prohibited as a result of your Country Monitor Risk Control Settings.)). Again, what's the best way to handle this for the user experience?

Thanks,
Gary Davis

Comment: 10486 - redirect the buyer back to PayPal to choose a different funding source.
10417 - no other funding source is available. restart the payment or tell the buyer his transaction was declined.
10537 - this is due to a Risk Control filter you set up on your account. The buyer triggered this filter, likely due to them paying from a country you don't currently allow. Either change your filter, or inform the buyer of this fact.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you're having problems. According to the PayPal community, this code indicates your card was declined by your bank; so your first course should be to get in touch with the card issuer. If that does not resolve, it's a simple matter to phone PayPal customer support, and here's the quickest way. Instead of phoning PayPal's 800 support number, go to this special page after logging in:

www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/helpscr?cmd=_contact-phone

To shortcut the seemingly interminable phone menu, repeat "Agent" in response to every prompt.

for more detials

https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/event_details_popup?eventId=3515

Comment: Thanks for helping out! Have a look at my response below; API error code 10486 is a new error code we recently introduced which lets you re-redirect buyers back to PayPal to reattempt a transaction with a different funding source (Bank, Bill me later or credit card). Hence the Q&A I posted here. :-)